# Windows task schduler keep showing 0x41301

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler, ps1

I have wrote the following .ps1 file:-

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
$request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("https://localhost/")
$response = $request.GetResponse()
$response.Close()
```

and I set a task within the windows server 2012 r2 task scheduler , to call te above ps1 file.now I run this task manually, but it keep showing "0x41301" which means it is still running ... although if I directly run the above code inside PowerShell window it will end in less than a second ? so why calling this ps1 using task Schuler will never ends ?

--Edit--
here is the XML exported:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2016-02-09T00:35:11.5514762</Date>
    <Author>ad-services\user.service</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <CalendarTrigger>
      <Repetition>
        <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
        <Duration>PT30M</Duration>
        <StopAtDurationEnd>false</StopAtDurationEnd>
      </Repetition>
      <StartBoundary>2016-02-09T19:30:01</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <ScheduleByDay>
        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
      </ScheduleByDay>
    </CalendarTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-20</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>true</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Users\user.service\Documents\AppPoolActivation.ps1</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Comment: You can enable that the task always ends in x minutes, hours, days, etc. Is it really a problem to kill the task this way? I've seen it before that a script ends, but the process remains active for some reason.

Comment: Can you post the exported XML from your Task so we can see exactly how you're setting it up?

Comment: @LPChip I did not get your point what is wrong with my script ?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I edit my question with the generated XML.. can you please check ? thanks

Comment: @JohnJohn My point is, that your script can be fine and run until completion, but the process still remains active and that keeps the scheduled task from stopping normally.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe this shows the problem:

```
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Users\user.service\Documents\AppPoolActivation.ps1</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
```

You shouldn't just put a .PS1 script in as the command you want to run, it will cause it to fail, or do weird things. :)

Instead in the Task, change the "Program/script" you want to run to:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Add the script via the "Arguments" field of the task, as well as include Execution Policy changes (if required).  i.e:

```
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Users\user.service\Documents\AppPoolActivation.ps1"
```

You may also want to change the "Start in" field to match the path that the script exists in, i.e.: `C:\Users\user.service\Documents\`.

Piece of advice, don't store the script in a user's profile folder, as it can cause access issues.  Instead make a folder (outside of the `Users` folder) to hold your script(s), and ensure the user account used to run the task has appropriate access.

Comment: I follow your steps and now I last run is showing 0x1 ?

Comment: @JohnJohn 0x1 means succesful if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Techie007 now the only approach which works in my case, is that I create a .bat file which calls the .pst file,, then inside the task scheduler  i specify the path to the .bat file inside the  "Program/script" ...

Comment: @LPChip 0x0 is SUCCESS. Any non-zero return value *usually* means error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as I had the task set to "run whether user is logged on or not".. When I switched it to "Run only when user is logged on" and tested it, I realized that I had a PAUSE in one of my batch files that I forgot to remove!

I know this is likely not related but hopefully it helps someone out in the future!

Comment: VLQ Reviewers: This is a legitimate attempt to answer the question. A `pause` command would indeed produce the task status code reported by the OP.

Comment: It solve my problem too

Answer (score 0):

Or simply in "Action" tab fill
Program/script: **powershell**
Addarguments (optional): **-NonInteractive -file** "C:\yourscript.ps1"